# Security inside PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a PHP file inside my project, which i use to establish connection with database. Inside this file there is a string `mysql_connect("server","username","password");` 
which contain real username and password for database. 
If i upload this file to the host anyone who will open this file and look inside of it will be able to learn my private data?

Comment: hmm, PHP and MySQL . my guess? yeppers, insecure

Comment: On this level? And there is no way around?

Comment: @Coffee ... PHP and MySQL does not magically make your app insecure ¬¬

Comment: You can put the file into a folder that can not be accessed via your domain and then just include it.

Comment: @Simeon will this have effect on other scripts that use this file, as connection bridge?

Comment: Yes you need to chance the path whenever you include the file. But if your file ends with .php and you set the right privileges, you are pretty save anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, anyone who has access to your server files will be able to look at your username/password. That will happen with any language you use. But people that will open your web application will not have that access. (if you set the proper permissions to the files/folders, of course)

Comment: So the solution is in setting right previlegies. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has access to your server, and has the right privileges, then yes, they will be able to see the file and its contents. If your server is set up properly then it should not be a problem; people, who visit your website, will only be able to see what PHP outputs.

Securing a server is a very big topic that cannot be answered satisfactorily here. If you want to secure a server then you should do some research.

Another thing: The [`mysql`](http://php.net/mysql_connect) extension was deprecated a long time ago. You should look into updating your database code and use something more secure, such as the [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/mysqli) extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Environment Variable - a bit secure, This [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/%E2%80%8E) tells how you can set them. use [getenv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function to get their value.

**Example:**

```
mysql_connect(getenv('server') , getenv('username') , getenv('password'));
```

Those have access to Environment Variable will be able to see only.

Answer (score 0):

1- In order to have better solutions, try using MVC platforms like CodeIgniter or Yii etc. 
2- For core PHP connection strings, you might want to keep them in a custom URL that is only known to you. 
3- You should not allow directory listing view for anonymous web users through use of error pages.

There are other security measures available that you might want to google as well.